# ionic2 observable dataservice

Tags: ionic2, observable, subscribe, dataservice

I'm new to Ionic 2 and it's observables. I have the following problem. I have a dataservice which has a function findAll. This function checks if the `private var products != false` if so it needs to return that value. if not, it needs to check the `nativestorage` and return that value if it is filled, if not, it checks http get and returns that

My problem, I wan't to subscribe to the `findAll` function, in case of  the http get this is possible, because it returns an observable (if i'm right), the nativestorage getitem returns a promise not an observable. and the first scenario of the already filled private variable is also not an observable.

Hopefully I described this problem clear enough

```
@Injectable()
export class dataService {
    products = false;

    constructor (http:Http) {
        this.http = http;
    } 

    findAll() {
        if (this.products !== false) {
            //HOWTO return this.products AS OBSERVABLE?
        } else {

            //HOWTO check native storage and return observable??
            NativeStorage.getItem('products') 

            //ELSE RETURN observable http get and 
            //HOWTO ADD TO this.products and NativeStorage.setItem
            return this.http.get(productsURL)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want can be achieved in the following way:

```
findAll():Observable<any[]> {
    if (this.products !== false) {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next(this.products);
            observer.complete();
        });
    } else {
        let localProducts = NativeStorage.getItem('products');

        return Observable.fromPromise(localProducts)
            .map(products => {
                if (products) {
                    return new Observable((observer) => {
                        observer.next(products);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
                } else {
                    return this.http.get(productsURL)
                            .map(response => response.json())
                            .catch(this.handleError)
                }
            });

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work, but code looked a bit verbose to me.

Comment: nick, I'll try this solution tonight. @KemalYalcinkaya is there a better way?